# HTTP 200 response code displayed as error in Blazemeter

Tags: jmeter

I'm executing a jmeter script which has a response assertion as HTTP 200, the same works fine in local machine.But when executing the same in Blazemeter, it marks the HTTP 200 response as error and fails the sample with the error as "Response was null", thus increasing the overall error %.

Note: Even the "Retrieve All Embedded Resources" are unchecked in the script.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Reach out to [BlazeMeter Support](https://www.blazemeter.com/support)
2. Show your [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configuration (most likely they will ask for it)
3. Show your response data (can be partial) or JMeter Variable you are performing assertion against.